# How can I use SOAPUI for REST call security testing

Tags: soapui

We have observed that not many tools offer a great support for Jason REST based services security and Penetration testing. Is there a  library of values I can use to feed to SOAPUI tests which can provide a large coverage of security tests?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of these built into newer versions of soapUI.  I believe from soapUI 4.0 on it is built in.  Take a look at the documentation on the [soapui website](http://soapui.org/Security/security-scans-overview.html)

Comment: There are some, however their library does not look equipped to support majority of the scans. Its has some tests but may not have all

Answer (score 0):

You can use SoapUi 4.6.4 Pro Version.It provides high coverage of security test.

**For example :** Boundry Scan,Cross Site Scripting,Custom Scripting,Fuzzy Scan,Invalid Types,SQL Injection,XPATH injection.

Please have a look at below link for understanding Security Testing using soapUi
http://www.soapui.org/security-testing/working-with-security-tests.html